# change wp-admin to /dashboard/ with htaccess on mutisite subfolder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multisite

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^/wp-admin/(.*)$ /dashboard/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^dash(.*)$ wp-admin$1
```

I use this code to change wp-admin to dashboard and works good but I can figure out how to get it to work on multi sites with subfolders

```
mysite.com/folder1
mysite.com/folder2
mysite.com/folder3
```

Comment: Did you try a more broad regex on something like http://www.regexr.com?

Comment: @bright-star Yes I can get the regex to work there but doesnt work in htaccess

Comment: Add what you tried to the question. It may help.